# Always these three

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

One of the figures have been blurred purposely (you'll understand why). Try come up with the correct answer.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> PLATONIC SOLIDS!

The first step is

> recognizing that the figures are the [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(polyhedron)) of the [Platonic Solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid).

The blurred one is

> the [Dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron)

The letters f v e

> mean faces vertices edges

In the table of numbers

> the five columns correspond to the five polyhedra. For each column if you locate the numbers of faces, vertices, and edges in its polyhedron, then take the corresponding letters/spaces from the following table, you spell out PLATONIC SOLIDS!

Comment: Everything good and as intended. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

The images at the top are

> Unfoldings of the platonic solids: shown are tetrahedron, hexahedron (AKA "cube"), octahedron, blurred image, and icosahedron.

therefore the missing image is

> a foldable dodecahedron [like this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Dodecahedron#/media/File:Foldable_dodecahedron_(structure).jpg).

Comment: You're correct on the missing figure but a full answer has been given by Cap so the tick goes to him.